# Instance of JavaFX controller is null

Tags: javafx

I am having trouble instantiating my controller class. When I try to make an instance it comes up null. I have been looking into previous posts about this and the closest I can get is:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/GuiFXML.fxml"));
scene = new Scene(root,1024,768);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setTitle("Proving Grounds");
stage.show();
GuiController controller = new GuiController();
controller.setTextArea("things and stuff");
```

Found these related questions but they seem to add more errors rather than fix anything.

[FXMLLoader get controller returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534480/fxmlloader-get-controller-returns-null)

[JavaFX controller is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910611/javafx-controller-is-always-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gui/GuiFXML.fxml"));
...
Parent root = loader.load();
...
GuiController controller = loader.getController();
...
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! it did make me cast loader.load() to parent. is that ok? it became
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();